# Pony mail in sinatra

Tags: ruby, sinatra, pony

How can I send mail to my gmail.com address using the Pony gem.

```
post '/contacts' do 
    @email = params[:email]
    @messages = params[:messages]
end
```

I tried the one described here, but it doesn't work.

```
Pony.mail(
  :name => params[:name],
  :mail => params[:mail],
  :body => params[:body],
  :to => 'a_lumbee@gmail.com',
  :subject => params[:name] + " has contacted you",
  :body => params[:message],
  :port => '587',
  :via => :smtp,
  :via_options => { 
     :address              => 'smtp.gmail.com', 
     :port                 => '587', 
     :enable_starttls_auto => true, 
     :user_name            => 'lumbee', 
     :password             => 'p@55w0rd', 
     :authentication       => :plain, 
     :domain               => 'localhost.localdomain'
})
```

Comment: Any extra detail, like an error message or something? Have you tried running the command in the console? Any chance that you haven't enabled your gmail account to be used via smtp? Please check [ask] to know how to improve your question, because with the provided details there's no much to do.

Comment: Just a reminder, you have exposed your password.

Answer (score 0):

**importantly** you must configure your gmail account: activate 2 factor authorisation and set an application password. It's a bit of searching, but not complicated.

I have configured like this in `app.rb`

```
configure :development do
    # use Pony to send emails. In development, use MailDev
    # run maildev in bash and go to http://localhost:1080
    set :via_options=> {
        :address        => 'localhost',
        :port           => '1025'
    }
end

configure :production do
    set :sessions, :domain => '.www.lafindumois.fr'
    set :via_options => {
         :address              => 'smtp.gmail.com',
         :port                 => '587',
         :enable_starttls_auto => true,
         :user_name            => 'blablablab@gmail.com',
         :password             => '', #application password generated by google in clear
         :authentication       => :plain, 
         :domain               => 'lafindumois.fr' # the HELO domain provided by the client to the server
    }
end
```

Usage:

```
if @user.save
        @valide_url = request.base_url + '/vali/'+@user.token
        Pony.mail({
            :to => @user.email,
            :via => :smtp,
            :via_options =>settings.via_options, #settings.via_options is avalable under configure above
            html_body: (erb :"emails/validemail", :layout => false)
        })
        erb :'enregis/enregistree', :layout => :layout_0
        else #irrelevant for this answer
        end #irrelevant for this answer
```